# NSNumber numberWithBool not an objective-c object

Tags: objective-c, boolean, nsnumber

I'm need to store some bool values in NSMutableDictionary, so I've founded a solution: using a [NSNumber numberWithBool] to make an object from bool.
It's work fine with value YES, but with NO it sometimes work fine, and sometimes result is "Not an objective-c object".
MyCode:

```
$ //sometimes fine, but sometimes "not an objective-c object"
$ NSNumber* nsn = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
```

I'm new to Objective-C, so i'm sorry if this is basic problem, but i really stuck with it.
Thanks for help.

Comment: why don't you just store NSNumber 1 or 0 (use them directly, not through numberWithBool) and then use in conditions `[storedNSNumber boolValue]`

Comment: this is really simple and effective solution, and looks like I will be use it. But now I'm just want to understand this behaviour =)

Comment: Sending the message `numberWithBool:` to the class `NSNumber` will always return an object, in particular an instance of `__NSCFBoolean`.  The problem must lie elsewhere.  When do you get the message "not an objective-c object"?  Please post more code.

Comment: I'm trying to put boolean value to a NSMutableDictionary, so I decided to use NSNumber.
All code looks like

    $ NSNumber *nsn = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
   $  [myDictionary setObject:nsn forKey:@"myKey"];

And this works not stable - sometimes fine, sometimes not.
I put breakpoint at this lines and after some iterations I recognized, that "nsn" sometime is @"0", and sometimes <not an Objective-C object>.
This is not depends of anything - I tried many conditions, and result is really independent.
P.S. sorry but I can't make a code block - I'm posting by phone.

Comment: Who says it is not an objective C object? The debugger? And if so, why would you care if the debugger is too stupid to recognize the object? Trust me, it is an object, always, regardless what anyone says.

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by `numberWithBool` and `initWithBool` seems to be initializing the NSNumber by a string and when you map the object in a dictionary it takes `NSValue` which indeed is null. Hence the dictionary will say it as null.

Answer (score 0):

Try either of:

```
NSObject * y1 = @(YES) ;
NSObject * n1 = @(NO) ;
NSObject * y2 = @YES ;
NSObject * n2 = @NO ;
```

Another example:

```
NSDictionary * testDict = @{
    @"key1": @YES
,   @"key2": @NO
} ;

BOOL b = [testDict[@"key1"] boolValue] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude. Why don't you just create your own class:

```
@interface Fool
{
   bool _amIFool;
}
@property bool amIFool;
@end

@implementation
-(bool)amIFool
{
   return _amIFool;
}

-(void)setAmIFool:(bool)amIFool
{
   _amIFool = amIFool
}

@end
```

Then you can shove it in a dictionary. Above code is just an example. You can write something better....

EDIT: You can even write a comparator, so you could directly do comparisons and stuff. And even write a convenience method so it is easy to initialise...

EDIT: Just FYI, my initial implementation was called "Cool". But since I'm not cool, I chose "Fool". You can do either.